# Analog Voltage and Current Measurement

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier

My requirement is to measure DC voltage in range 20 to 80 using a microcontroller.

Its is stated in the microcontroller datasheet that "The maximum recommended impedance for analog sources is 2.5 kΩ." and the analog input range of the microcontroller is 0-5v.

I am restricted to do this by using voltage divider and op amp. Here scaling down of voltage is done, is it possible to have the gain of op amp less than unity.

I am an absolute beginner so pls provide me a circuit and explain what is the role of op amp (since scale down of voltage can be achieved by voltage divider itself).

Answer (score 1):

A non-inverting amplifier always has a voltage gain greater than one- the formula is Vout/Vin = (1 + Rf/Rz). But you can attenuate the signal before the op-amp sees it, and have a gain as little as one (for example Rf = 0, Rz = open).

The op-amp will have a closed-loop output impedance much less than 2.5K, so your requirement will be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

> Its is stated in the microcontroller datasheet that "The maximum
>   recommended impedance for analog sources is 2.5 kΩ." and the analog
>   input range of the microcontroller is 0-5v.

You don't *have* to use an op-amp, just a potential divider comprised of 2 resistors: -

[image]

If you make R2 2.4 kohm (to satisfy your first requirement) then R1 could be 36 kohm. This means that with 80V inputted the output will be exactly 5V. This doesn't leave much headroom so you might choose to make R1 = 39 kohm.

With 80V applied across ~40 kohm the power dissipation is 160 mW. Is this too high? Is the impedance to 80V too low? If yes then you will need the complexity of an op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have asked many questions and concepts in one go.
Yes gain of opamp can be less than unity, if applied properly.
Below is circuit, which u can use.[image]

First potential divider will reduce your input voltage, as u said, but if u connect this directly to microcontroller, output voltage will change depending on current drawn by microcontroller(which will depend on your input voltage); thus exact voltage is not measured by microcontroller.

What opamp does here is that, whatever current is being required by microcontroller, is drawn by the power source( connected to opamp, +12,-12V) instead of ur input voltage source(which u want to measure). First opamp configuration in image is called unity gain buffer(please refer internet), whose work is to maintain same voltage irrespective of current drawn by next circuitry to great extent. Next opamp will help u in fine tuning of ur complete gain.

This voltage stabilization phenomena  is termed in technical term as output impedance of circuit, which will be input impedance to micro-controller. 
You can visualize complete circuit in image as input voltage source in series with an impedance, which will be connected to microcontroller. If u visualize like this, u will definitely want impedance to be ideally zero, so that no drop occurs across it, and exact voltage is measured/given to microcontroller.

More the value of this impedance, more drop will occur across it for a particular value of current drawn. So ideally its value should be zero. But micro-controller is giving u privilege to keep it at high value, because, inside micro-controller, they are using some circuitry to reduce the current drawn from ur voltage sensing circuitry.

Comment: Please correct your language, so that someone else does not have to. "u" and "ur" are not English words, which you probably know since you use "You" in your text as well. This looks sloppy.